# Regex expression to replace word before search pattern

Tags: regex

I am very confused how to replace a word before pattern ".ext".

example :

Before Replace : abcd.ext.com

After Replace : customer.ext.com

Comment: What language are you working in?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `[^.]+(?=\.)` as the match and replace it by `customer`.

`(?=\.)` is a positive lookahead which will match when there is a dot following the part before, but it won't match any characters on its own.

E.g. in C# you can use

```
Regex.Replace(foo, @"[^.]+(?=\.)", "customer");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in C# then I would recommend you just doing something like this:

```
var newFileName = fileName.Replace(Path.GetFileName(fileName), "newFileNameValue");
```

If it's in VB.NET, it would look almost exactly the same:

```
Dim newFileName As String = fileName.Replace(Path.GetFileName(fileName), "newFileNameValue")
```

You can use a Regex, but it's probably a little overkill and less stable. See, when building a Regex you have to break it down to a really abstract level. You need to handle every extension that's in your domain and that list can grow pretty quickly. So then it's generally not feasible to include those extensions in the Regex itself.

To further add to the problem, a valid file name might be something like this, `MyFile.v1.l1.ext1.txt`. The extension of that file is `.txt`, but grabbing that with a Regex is tough.

Answer (score 0):

On Unix you can use sed like this:

```
echo "$str"|sed 's/abcd\(\.ext\)/customer\1/'
```

i.e. look for abcd immediately followed by `.ext` (capture this in a group). Then replace it with `customer` and match group #1 (`.ext`)

If you're using any other platform/language approach should be same.

Answer (score 0):

## perl

```
 $x =~ s/(.*)(\.ext\.com)/customer$2/;
```